# ASP.NET View doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem which is strange to me. I'm making MVC project and when I on my website click on Contact it doesn't redirect me to Contact page, it shows this message:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhDZI.png)
error text :Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

and code behind is:

```
<li>
<a href="~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml">Contact</a>
</li>
```

if I go under folder View and directly open in Firefox Contact.cshtml it opens normally... PLz help, as I'm noob..

Comment: Please include the text of the error in your question as text, not as an image.

Comment: @user6533736 Could you the screen shot of the project?

Comment: what exactly should I screenshot?

Comment: Whats the actual URL that is generated in your browser?

Comment: this is URL : http://localhost:56895/Home/Index         and when click on links this Url shows: http://localhost:56895/Views/Home/About.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

In MVC projects, View files are not served directly, they always go through a Controller Action first.

This is because a View file needs some data to go into it first (the View-model), and it's the Controller's responsibility to create the View-model.

If your View does not actually require any data, then you can write a Controller action that serves it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Contact() {

        return this.View(); // returns the "Contact" view under "Home", these values are inferred from the Controller's name "HomeController" and the action name "Contact"
    }
}
```

Your link should then look like `<a href="@Url.Action( "Contact", "Home" )>Contact</a>`

Or `@Html.ActionLink( "Contact", "Home" )

Alternatively, if you want a simple website comprised only of `.cshtml` then look at ASP.NET WebPages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started

Comment: Hey, I tried as you suggested but nothing changed, I get sam error. I already had that controller automatically set, because I used Bootstrap template. Don't know what to do... I was searching on web, someone suggested it could be connected to IIS, I updated the server....is that a problem or? Because I don't know what to do..I'm stuck on basics 101...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started - Getting Started with MVC 5

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. It was so simple, that I am ashamed what error have I done.... Only thing I need to make was this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contact","Contact", "Home")
```

and inside list delete `<a href="#">Contact</a>`

so the final result with which I am navigating from index.cshtml to other views is:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("About","About", "Home")
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Contact","Contact", "Home")
                </li>
            </ul>
```